# able to vs. capable of

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs

a. Although my arm was injured, I was able to take the gun out of the drawer, but I didn't.

b. Although my arm was injured, I was capable of taking the gun out of the drawer, but I didn't.

=========================

c. When I was young, I was probably able to run for over an hour, but I never tried to do so.

d. When I was young, I was probably capable of running for over an hour, but I never tried to do so.

Are the above sentences grammatically correct and meaningful?

I think the ones with 'able to' do not work. They imply that I did do what I am talking about, but the sentences say that I didn't.

Comment: IMO "capable" shows more certainty rather than able.

Comment: The expressions seem less likely than "...I could have..." and "...I probably could have...".

Comment: "I was able to..." implies that you did do it. "I could have..." or "I would have been able to..." (implying 'if I had wanted to').